# Users provisioning with ansible takes too long

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have playbook that provisions user to remote host:

```
---
- hosts: webserver
  remote_user: myuser
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Add ssh Users
      authorized_key: user='ubuntu' key="{{ lookup('file', './keys/{{item}}.pub') }}"
      with_items:
        - user1
        - user2
        - user3
        - user4
        - user5
        - user6
        - user7
        - user8
        - user9
        - user10
        - user11
        - user12
```

This single task takes 110 seconds and that is very slow.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ./inventory setup_ssh.yaml -vvv
Using /vagrant/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in setup_ssh.yaml

...

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0

Wednesday 27 July 2016  07:38:39 +0000 (0:01:50.486)       0:02:00.054 ********
===============================================================================
TASK: ssh_keys : Add ssh Users ---------------------------------------- 110.49s
TASK: setup ------------------------------------------------------------- 9.49s
```

Check out [full log](https://gist.github.com/korney4eg/dc6f3988a2d4c8b58d2eafa5cbb393d3).

I tried to enable pipelining, but it didn't help.

I'm using ansible 2.0.0.2
Here is my ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = inventory
host_key_checking = false
roles_path = ./roles
private_key_file = ~/.ssh/id_rsa
deprecation_warnings=False
remote_user = ubuntu
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
pipelining = true

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By specifying:

```
ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes
```

you've replaced ansible's defaults:

```
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

thus disabled ssh connection reuse. Add this options to your config and try again.

If time gain will not be enough, you may want to concatenate all .pub files locally first and then execute `authorized_key` module once with multiline string as key parameter – this module can handle it.

Comment: I used your suggestion, now ssh configuration looks like that:
```ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s```

Accroding to your second suggestion, I can't use single file, because I use more then one evironment with different sets of users.

Answer (score 1):

`authorized_key` task from original question was executed for every user and every time reconnected to server. In this case every connection took about 7 seconds.
First I tried [answer from Konstantin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608610/1812058) and that decrease time to run to 48 seconds. I was curious if result could be improved.
I successfully solved my issue by using template which generates all ssh keys:

```
---
- hosts: webserver
  remote_user: myuser
  sudo: yes
  vars:
    ssh_users: ['user1','user2','user3','user4','user5','user6','user7','user8','user9','user10','user11','user12']
  tasks:
  - name: Add ssh Users
    template:
      dest=/home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
      src=templates/authorized_keys
      owner=myuser
      group=myuser
      mode=600
```

And template file looks like:

```
{% for user in ssh_users %}
{{ lookup('file', './keys/'+user+'.pub') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my final ansible configuration:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = inventory
host_key_checking = false
roles_path = ./roles
private_key_file = ~/.ssh/id_rsa
deprecation_warnings=False
remote_user = ubuntu
callback_whitelist = profile_tasks
pipelining = true

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes  -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

Now it looks much faster.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ./inventory setup_ssh.yaml -vv
Using /vagrant/ansible.cfg as config file
1 plays in setup_backend_test.yaml

PLAY [Configure common packages] ***********************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
Wednesday 27 July 2016  14:23:48 +0000 (0:00:00.063)       0:00:00.063 ********
ok: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]

TASK [ssh_keys : Add ssh Users] ************************************************
Wednesday 27 July 2016  14:23:54 +0000 (0:00:06.025)       0:00:06.088 ********
changed: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] => {"changed": true, "checksum": "3df874356f41d3dc5592441a86060d2796b4a714", "dest": "/home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys", "gid": 1000, "group": "myuser", "md5sum": "4c7d6c58a618a9fbd5e5ed3b29a3e7d3", "mode": "0600", "owner": "myuser", "size": 5357, "src": "/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469629434.59-30865046320342/source", "state": "file", "uid": 1000}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

Wednesday 27 July 2016  14:24:02 +0000 (0:00:07.855)       0:00:13.944 ********
===============================================================================
TASK: ssh_keys : Add ssh Users ------------------------------------------ 7.85s
TASK: setup ------------------------------------------------------------- 6.03s
```

Comment: Template is a bit different thing – it may overwrite keys added to authorized_keys by other means. But anyway – it's another way to get rid of with_items, which makes things significantly faster.